How can I integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Flutter app to receive real chat message notifications instead of dummy messages?
I'm working on a Firebase chat application and have integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to receive notifications for chat messages. However, I'm currently only receiving dummy messages instead of actual chat message notifications. I'm looking for a way to properly integrate FCM so that notifications are triggered by real chat messages and displayed correctly in the app. Can Anyone Help me .
I've integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) into my chat application to receive notifications. However, when I try to connect FCM to my chat messages, it asks for a server key, which I discovered is deprecated in Firebase Cloud Messaging. I'm looking for a solution to properly integrate FCM so that I can receive actual chat message notifications without relying on the deprecated server key. Can you guide me on how to set this up correctly or provide a query to handle notifications for my chat messages?
